# Definitive on timeline_type?

Tags: support, api, documentation, timeline

Hi all,

I am trying to get a definitive on what timeline_type actually means...

I've looked at: https://stackapps.com/search?q=timeline_type but to no avail.

The new documentation doesn't list anything (http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-timelines) and the old documentation (http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=questions/{id}/timeline) appears deprecated...

This is what the old documentation has - "question, answer, comment, revision, votes, state, accepted, or unaccepted"...

Are votes and state still in operation and if so what do they mean?  Are Votes up down etc and what is state?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [enumerations page](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/enumerations) on the documentation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to explain their meaning though.